# Creating Materialized view in oracle taking forever

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have following query which has select query that returns data in 5sec. But when I add create materialized view command infront it takes ever for the query to create materialized view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a materialized view, you actually create a copy of the data that Oracle takes care to keep synchronized (and it makes those views somewhat like indexes). If your view operates over a big amount of data or over data from other servers, it's natural that the creating this view can take time.

From [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm):

> A materialized view is a replica of a target master from a single
>   point in time.

Comment: Why does the query time is small but not view create time. My query runs on linked server

Comment: @Kitex, I can't be 100% sure since it depends on many variables, but one possible reason can be because of local data storage constraints. Other reason can be because your view is over a large amount of data and your query is over a subset of this data.

Comment: Or because you're timing the arrival of the first row of data, but building the MV relies on receiving all the data. That can also lead to a different execution plan.

Comment: @DavidAldridge timing the arrival of the first row of data?

Comment: @GerardoLima yea the query is over large amount of data .

Comment: When you execute the query you may get the first rows of data returned to the client within seconds, but it may take minutes for the query to complete. Be careful that you're comparing the time to retrieve all of the data with the time to create the materialized view.

Comment: It's natural that creating a materialized view over a large amount of data from a remote server takes time, since it's made of slow physical operations (reading all data from disk, sending through network, saving to disk, creating control structures...). The good part is that, after this view is created, accessing times should be faster.

Comment: Maybe your query over the remote server seems fast because it operates only within a sub-range of the data. And @DavidAldridge has his point, too: maybe it *seems* fast because your application doesn't need to wait for all rows to return and can start processing after the first rows are available.

Comment: As a suggestion you could consider: if now you get good results from querying the remote server, why don't you create a regular view? If later you experience network problems you can always recreate the view as materialized.

Comment: @Gerardo Lima I can't create view because query would always take 5-15 minutes.

Comment: Hi, @Kitex, you first said your query directly to the remote server tables would only take 5 sec... If your query lead to such high times it is another symptom that it's natural for the materialized query to take a long time -- because of low network speed, slow local I/O or a big amount of data. Try to schedule its creation to a low system usage time (like 2 am) so it does not compete with other running processes.

Comment: @GerardoLima the query is to live database it sometime takes 5 sec sometime 15 min or sometime just hangs for long time and I have to kill the session and start it. I need fresh data every hour or so :(

Answer (score 1):

Just for "yuks", try 
create table temp_tab nologging as select ...

I've seen cases where MV creation is long for some reason, probably logging.

Also, query development tools sometimes begin returning the data to the screen right away, but if you "paged" to the last row, you would find out how long it really takes to get all the data.

You should profile the select statement with explain plan and understand the table cardinality, indexes, waits states when running, ... in order to see if the query needs tuning.